# How do I create and name objects when I run my program?

Tags: java, runtime, naming

Is it possible to have my program name objects as they're created?  Such as using a loop that names objects object1, object2, etc.. This is an issue because it won't always be clear how many objects are necessary, it depends on the users input.  Or is there another way to get around this without having to name the objects?

Comment: Use an array or a collection.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot create references dynamically as you have mentioned but you can always use a collection of objects. If you know the number of objects upfront, then go for `Array` otherwise go for a `List` for dynamic number of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hashtable of names and objects, which you append to as you create each object.

If the objects are of the same class, you can add an attribute to the class to contain the name.